# Dynamic class loading in Spring/Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

I am currently using

```
String myClass; // dynamically determined class name
Class.forName(myClass).newInstance()
```

to dynamically load objects in a spring app deployed to a tomcat server.

I've been reading (http://blog.bjhargrave.com/2007/09/classforname-caches-defined-class-in.html) that it a preferred approach to dynamically loading classes is using the  `ClassLoader.loadClass`, such as

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(myClass).newInstance()
```

In the second example, using `loadClass`, I am getting an error that the class is not found. I suspect this is because I'm running within Tomcat the system class loader is not the class loader I actually want to be using.

When in a Tomcat app, which class loader should I be using if I want to use the loadClass mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you want to use the classloader that loaded your currently executing code. That is, you just want to call `getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(...)`. That said, there are times when you need to use a different class loader. When that is necessary requires hours and hours of training. So, you should always use the loader that loaded the currently executing code.

Comment: In this case I'm trying to load the class from a string name so I don't have the class object...

Comment: no, not the loader for the class you want to load, the class loader that loaded your class. You must be executing in some class, like HttpServlet or something, right? So you just call `this.getClass().getClassLoader()` to get the right loader.

Comment: Or if in a static context, `ThisClass.class`. Either way, you get the "current" class, then the current class loader. But that's exactly what `Class.forName()` is doing. So `Class.forName()` is usually what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getClassLoader().loadClass(myClass).newInstance()` ,

It will look for the class in current classloader and will go to the parent classloader if not found.

myClass should be the fully qualified name like `java.lang.String`